# Nem todas as imagens são carregadas pelo navegador

Tags: html, imagem, cdn, jpg

Tenho uma página que precisa carregar cerca de 1200 fotos e sempre funcionou bem. Mas na última leva de fotos surge um erro na página conforme mostrado abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesses ícones que aparecem se eu clicar com o botão direito e depois em carregar as fotos são corrigidas. Mas não dá pra fazer isso manualmente pois centenas de fotos estão aparecendo com esse erro.
Segue abaixo o código resumido que carrega essas fotos:

```
<body>
  <figure><img src='https://www.outstandingaward.com/2in9ix/OM014-4142-2020531157400.jpg'> 
     <figcaption>OM014-4142-2020531157400.jpg<br/>13ordesandra@gmail.com</figcaption></figure>
  <figure><img src='https://www.outstandingaward.com/2in9ix/OM014-4142-20205311511470.jpg'> 
     <figcaption>OM014-4142-20205311511470.jpg<br/>13ordesandra@gmail.com</figcaption></figure>
  <figure><img src='https://www.outstandingaward.com/2in9ix/OM014-4142-20205311512440.jpg'> 
     <figcaption>OM014-4142-20205311512440.jpg<br/>13ordesandra@gmail.com</figcaption></figure>
  <!--centena de outras fotos-->
```

Alguém sabe dizer se é erro do servidor? Ou algum probleminha no código acima?
Obs.: 
- O código acima foi feito direto no html. Se eu fizer via asp.net o erro persiste.
- Meu site utiliza Cloudflare. Isso pode ser causado pelo Cloudflare?
- Testei no Chrome, Firefox e Opera. Em todos o mesmo erro.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: já deu uma olhada na aba "rede/network" das ferramentas do navegador para ver o que acontece, porque não carregou? pode ser problema de link direto ao cloudflare

Comment: Ou é o seu sistema operacional ou browser engasgando com a quantidade de requisições, são imagens demais para uma página web

Comment: Até entendo que são muitas imagens, mas essa página é feita a cada 3 meses, sempre com a mesma quantidade de fotos ou mais e é a primeira vez que deu erro.

Comment: Ricardo Pontual - Dei uma olhada e para as fotos não carregadas deu erro 503. Parece ser alguma nova limitação do servidor de hospedagem.

Comment: +- 350 KB x 1200 = 420MB Quantos acessos por hora?

Comment: Use _lazy load_ que deve resolver. As fotos serão carregadas aos poucos à medida que entram no viewport.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Essa não é uma página pública, um acesso por vez. Apenas para verificação.

Comment: @Sam Obrigado Sam, vou tentar. Obrigado.

Comment: Eu tenho um código de lazyload que eu mesmo fiz e funciona que é uma beleza. Vou até atualizar depois pq parece que o classList tá obsoleto. Mas segue aí se quiser testar: https://jsfiddle.net/xz2a75Lw/

Comment: ops @Sam. Muito obrigado.